# Is it possible to set table column widths without dragging?

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

InDesign is amazing, but how can I set table column widths without dragging their borders with the mouse?

I mean (= I hope to find) a window where I can specify the width of each column, either in picas/points or percentage. Does it exist somewhere?

Something like this:

[image]

Or, what is the "mainstream" or recommended way to create tables like "40-15-15-15-15"? (The values are given as percentage.)

I have a document where some tables should be "40-15-15-15-15" and some "52-12-12-12-12". I'm trying to figure out how to create them properly and how to handle such cases in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **Table Panel**. Here you can specify the *Column Width* (and other useful settings).

You can't enter percentages (or rather they work *relative* to the current cell size), but you could enter the percentages in a physical unit and then drag the table to fit the text frame. Perhaps you need to reenter the wanted *Row Height* afterwards as you might change the height.

Another way of being able to set percentages could be to use copy/paste in a clever way. If the width of your text frame for example is 120 mm, copy `%*120mm` to the clipboard. Then select a column, enter the wanted percentage, paste and press enter.

[image]

All of these settings also appear in the *Control Panel* (the vertical toolbar in the top of the window) when you select a table or part of it.

See [the manual](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-tables.html) for all the basics about tables.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But it seems I cannot specify all of the values in one step (see the screenshot I have just added), and there will be at least 2 steps (or more). That is, for a table like 40-15-15-15-15% it will be two steps, and for a table like 20-10-40-20-10% it will be 5 steps, right?

Comment: Yeah. Doesn't sound too terrible to me.  Once you've adjusted one table you can just copy/paste it around. I'm pretty sure the functionality you dream about doesn't exist. You could write a script for it if it really bothers you. But how many seconds will it save you per table? And how many tables do you have?

Comment: I just discovered https://github.com/gsingelmann/indd_autocolumn, but still thanks!

Comment: @johnc.j., that's neat! I was thinking something like that. Sadly doesn't seem to allow percentages though. Or any other units than the default for the document.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this was not asked, but I have never seen it difficult to drag the columns to exact widths if needed. I have prepared some rectangles by inputting numerically their dimensions and dragged table columns (and rows as well, if needed ) to snap to them.

Comment: In such a case it will be better to use guidelines, probably...

Comment: Rectangles have worked well - They can be placed and pasted from another program. In addition there can well be a harmfully full field of quidelines.. But a few quidelines only -  that will work well.